# Passing and getting Values from Controller Action to Ajax Success - Yii Framework

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii

I am new to yii Framework now I want to pass value from Controller action to Ajax on Success and by getting the value I have store it in php variable . How to achieve this ?

**My Controller Action :**

```
public function actionNewrefList($id)
    {
        $model=new RefListModel();
        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['RefListModel']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['RefListModel'];
            $model->crm_base_contact_id=$id;
            if($model->save())
            {
                /** Here i need to send value of $model->crm_ref_list_id to Ajax Onsuccess **/
                return;
            }
        }


    }
```

**My View Ajax:**

```
echo CHTML::ajaxSubmitButton('Save', Yii::app()->createUrl('baseContact/NewrefList',array("id" => $base)),
           array('success' => 'js:function(){
    '))
```

Here I have to get the value passed from controller and store it in PHP Variable.

Comment: post var_dump of your $model->crm_ref_list_id

Comment: @Letmesee alert(data) prints whole array and the crm_ref_list_id but i want to get crm_ref_list_id alone in OnSuccess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if(isset($_POST['RefListModel']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['RefListModel'];
        $model->crm_base_contact_id=$id;
        if($model->save())
        {
            echo $model->crm_ref_list_id;
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
```

In view:

```
echo CHTML::ajaxSubmitButton('Save', 
Yii::app()->createUrl('baseContact/NewrefList',
array("id" => $base)),
'success' => 'js:function(data){
    alert(data);
}'))
```

Comment: alert(data) prints whole array and the crm_ref_list_id but i want to get crm_ref_list_id alone in OnSuccess.

Comment: `echo $model->crm_ref_list_id;` pass here what you need.

Comment: +1 ineersa... @manadh your simply need to **echo** the value you want as **data** in your javascript code.

Comment: data will print whatever you are sending from the server. so check the value what you are sending. its not javascript fault what you are getting

Comment: how to use echo in JavaScript

Comment: it's not in js, it's in your controller action.